# With of submit element compared to div

Tags: css

When I have a submit/button element and I assign a fixed with, the padding is subtracted from the width. When I apply this to a normal div element the padding is added to the width.

Can somebody point me where this behaviour is explained?

```
.green_submit { 
    color: #fff; 
    background-color: #94c909; 
    padding: 25px; 
   width: 200px;
```

}

`<input type="submit" class='green_submit' value="Validate" />`

Will result in a width of 146px.

`<div class="green_submit"></div>`

Will result in a width of 200px

http://jsfiddle.net/nnnS3/29/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `box-sizing` is not consistent between the two.  Use `box-sizing: border-box` to have the padding and border included in the width.

http://jsfiddle.net/nnnS3/30/

Alternatively, use `content-box` for both (but the `<div>` does not have a border):

http://jsfiddle.net/nnnS3/31/

Comment: In Firefox this doesn't change anything... In Chrome it's better yes.

Comment: @Rogier21 try `-moz-box-sizing`

Answer (score 1):

Input elements and most form controls have a default value of `border-box` for the `box-sizing` property .. you can double check this by scanning the default UA styles in your browsers developer tools. If you want the behavior to be consistent among the two elements you can use one of the values of the [`box-sizing`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing) property, which was introduced in CSS3. The `border-box` value constrains the elements padding and border areas to the elements specified width/height

```
.green_submit {
box-sizing: border-box; /* | padding-box (support is bad) | content-box */
}
```

Comment: Same as the other answers: In firefox this is still as before, in Chrome it's right. So I suppose the support for box-sizing is not really implemented yet.

Comment: You'll need to add the moz prefix, e.g. `moz-box-sizing: border-box;` for FF